# Cassandra Spark Connector - Where condition involving multiple partition

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Lets consider with key as ((PK1,PK2),Data1)

How to make query with where

(PK1="A" and PK2 in (1,2,3) and data1 > 1 and data1 < 2) or (PK1="B" and PK2 in (1,2,3) and data1 > 1 and data1 < 2)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use an or operator like that, so you would probably create two RDD's, one for "SELECT * FROM t WHERE PK1='A' AND PK2 IN (1,2,3) AND data1 > 1 AND data1 < 2" and one for "SELECT * FROM t WHERE PK1='B' AND PK2 IN (1,2,3) AND data1 > 1 AND data1 < 2".

Then you could combine them into a single RDD with the spark **union** function.

Comment: I see issue #37 and Issue #154 , do you think the above two issues will be covering this scenario, I have gone through the changes specified but still not clear